# String Format when Export to Excel From gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel, gridview, string-formatting

I Have export Gridview data to excel, here's my code :

```
 Protected Sub btnExport_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExport.Click
        Try
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            If CReversal.SearchReversal2(txtAccount.Text, txtCustName.Text, txtAmount.Text, dropResponse.SelectedValue.ToString, txtRefNo.Text, txtDate.Text) Then
                dt = CReversal.DT
            Else
                eMessage("System failure: ", CReversal.eMsg)
            End If
            Dim DataGrd As New DataGrid()
            DataGrd.DataSource = dt.DefaultView
            DataGrd.DataBind()

            Dim attachment As String
            attachment = "attachment; filename=Inquiry_Report" & Format(Now, "ddMMMyyyy") & ".xls"
            Response.Buffer = True
            Response.ClearContent()
            Response.ClearHeaders()
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment)
            Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel"
            Dim sw As New StringWriter()
            Dim htw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
            DataGrd.RenderControl(htw)
            Response.Write(sw.ToString())
            Response.End()
        Catch ex As Exception
            eMessage("Export Data failure: ", ex.ToString())
        End Try

    End Sub
```

the export process is run as i want. but when i open the excel file, i got some strings number character become like this :

[image]
but actually the datagridvie display is like this : 
[image: should]

is it possible to format the string number character when we want to export to excel programatically? thk you

Comment: I've found that in Excel, if you need a number to appear exactly as entered, putting an apostrophe `'` before the number makes it appear correctly.

Comment: is there any way to do that progrmatically?

Comment: How do you write to Excel?
Your problem is caused by excel, which converts certain numbers to such carbage. YOur number should be written as a text cell, so Excel displays the raw text, no matter what.
This is fearly easy if you use one of the free excel libraries like EPPLUS, but next to impossible if you us csv.

Comment: @ChristianSauer i get the value from data table, and write the excel, like i wrote above, i try to avoid use external libraries.

Comment: The problem with your approach is, that you are not writing "real" excel data. It is a html table which CAN be read by excel, but you are not really able to influence the way excel reads this mess.
Libraries like EPPLus are much better at writing excel file and reduce your headaches by orders of magnitude. It is free, even in commercial contexts, so no problems when you use it. Just better results

Comment: @ChristianSauer yep , look like i should try your recommendation. thank you :)

Comment: I add this as answer :)

Comment: @SabilValdano - yes it can be done progrmatically, either prepend the apostrophe in your database query, or update the appropriate column in your DataGrid before writing it to the output stream. This would still work for CSV  output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your approach is, that you are not writing "real" excel data. It is a html table which CAN be read by excel, but you are not really able to influence the way excel reads this mess. Libraries like EPPLus are much better at writing excel file and reduce your headaches by orders of magnitude. It is free, even in commercial contexts, so no problems when you use it. Just better results

As a side note: Epplus supports a "LoadFromDataTable" method- with a little luck, that all you need...